# terminate a connection CBPeripheralManager side

Tags: osx-mavericks, core-bluetooth

Is there a recommended way for `CBPeripheralManager` to terminate a connection. The best way I have found so far is simply not to respond to dynamic value, then the BLE stack seems to close the connection, but that seems rather crude.

There must be a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't forcefully close a connection in a clear way from the peripheral side. There is no API for it.

You can break the connection abruptly by not responding to a request, which results in disconnection at most after 30 seconds. This is the standard behavior defined by the Bluetooth specification Vol.3 Part F 3.3.3

> A transaction not completed within 30 seconds shall time out. Such a
>   transaction shall be considered to have failed and the local higher
>   layers shall be informed of this failure. No more attribute protocol
>   requests, commands, indica- tions or notifications shall be sent to
>   the target device on this ATT Bearer.

Comment: This is a strange situation, closing a connection on the peripheral side, isn't an uncommon requirement. Even if its just for testing as in my case. Its something that we all experience! even if we don't programmatically request it.

Comment: Apple engieers say in iOS many applications can use the same peripheral. They were struggling to get a meaningful way to cancel a given connection but everything was too ambiguous. So they ended up with not having a way to cancel a connection. You need to implement your own protocol to notify the central about the disconnection request. I added an alternative, less clean solution to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the back story. My problem is I want to simulate the un-expected! an un-expected dropped connection by a peripheral. I have to ask myself how Apple performs its own regression testing? I guess I'll just have to keep using my side effect method, which does the trick and is probably more realistic anyway.

Comment: Oh, ok. I just realized you described that method in the question. I added the standard reference to the answer to make it complete. I'm not sure how much they test but I suspect they don't gave any help on how we should do it. If you want to test the Core Bluetooth functionality, then the side effect thing is ok. However, to test your business logic it may be better to separate it from the framework and test it with unit tests. Coordinated, multi-device tests are hard, if not impossible to create anyway.

Comment: BTW. Do you think I answered your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the BT spec & I think you answered the question. There is definitely a need for an open source BT test framework. I did think using a Mac would be a good way to simulate a peripheral. As it is local to the XCTest, it made sense, being able to control both sides of the connection, however now I am not quite so sure! the implementation of CBPeripheralManager seems rather constrained. I think it deserves a little more effort before giving up.

Comment: Creating an automated test is really hard. Not just because it is a distributed system but because in many cases the stack contains faults that are usually activated under stress. Creating a testing environment that handles these cases is practically impossible. Having a mock implementation may be a better option. However, if you feel the power to come up with some creative, simple way for testing, then I will wholeheartedly endorse it.