# how to build a secure BLE connection when many-central-to-one-peripheral is supported

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

So, I understand that it is supported, in BLE, to have multiple centrals to connect a single peripheral:

https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/24160/multiple-central-to-single-peripheral-connections

At the same time, I see that there is no way for a peripheral to disconnect a central:

[terminate a connection CBPeripheralManager side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537427/terminate-a-connection-cbperipheralmanager-side)

What we are attempting to do is to have some app-level authenticating back-and-forth right after a connection.  C provides a challenge question, P must reply correctly, P provides a challenge question, C must answer correctly, and only then will P start updating its data characteristic.  Otherwise it resumes advertising and waits for a new connection attempt.

This worked great in the one-to-one case, but in the multiple-C-to-single-P scenario, we can't just stop updating data if the authentication fails, because there may be previously connected centrals that still need the updates.  Is there really no way for a peripheral to "kick" a specific central from being connected to it?

Otherwise I'm not sure how to implement two-way app-level authentication between central and peripheral, while supporting multiple centrals.  Is this really not supported?

Comment: Is your peripheral an iOS device, an Android device, an nRF device or something else?

Comment: Both central and peripheral are iOS devices.

Comment: I guess you are right, iOS doesn't seem to expose any way to, in the peripheral mode, disconnect a central.